# Open iOS 11 Files app via URL Scheme or some other way

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, url-scheme, files-app

My app is now sharing `Documents` directory on iOS 11 Files app "On My iPhone" section.

(Thanks to this article: [Working with the Files App in iOS 11](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/))

Question is how to open this directory or at least File app root page via URL Scheme. `UIDocumentPickerViewController` or `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` doesn't help in this situation.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this too. Could not find something yet.

Comment: There is a thread about this in the Apple Developer Forums but without any answer yet: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/257860#257860

Answer (score 6):

```
    guard let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first,
          let components = NSURLComponents(url: documentDirectory, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
        return
    }
    components.scheme = "shareddocuments"
    
    if let sharedDocuments = components.url {
        UIApplication.shared.open(
            sharedDocuments,
            options: [:],
            completionHandler: nil
        )
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, describe how this part of code is working, will make your answer more usable

Comment: Using this snippet you can find the documents directory and replace the URL scheme from file:// to shareddocuments://, that is needed to open the Files app.

Comment: This works as of iOS 15

Answer (score 2):

The Files app can be opened with the URL scheme `shareddocuments://`.

I don’t know if there’s a way to open a specific directory however.

Answer (score 1):

```
    func openSharedFilesApp() {
        let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let sharedurl = documentsUrl.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "shareddocuments://")
        print(sharedurl)
        let furl:URL = URL(string: sharedurl)!
        UIApplication.shared.open(furl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

This code would work.