# Cannot Find Private URL For Opening Files App From Within Another App On iOS

Tags: swift, cydia-substrate

I need to open up the Files app from within my app. This is an internal application not going on the app store so I'm not worried about trying to use private URLs.

I've tried

```
"App-Prefs:root=files"
"App-Prefs:root=FILES"
"App-Prefs:root=Files"
```

in

```
let url = URL.init(string: "App-Prefs:root=Files")!
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { (Bool) in
    print("opened")
}
```

Depending on the string it will either not open anything or open the settings application.

Comment: The url scheme for the Files app is `shareddocuments://`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499842/open-ios-11-files-app-via-url-scheme-or-some-other-way) thread, you can use `shareddocuments://` as the `URLScheme` to open the Files app. You can read more about how to use `URLSchemes` in [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) document in the section called Using URL Schemes to Communicate with Apps.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the code:

```
    // give your initial URL as fileUrl
let sharedPath = fileUrl.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "shareddocuments://")
                                guard let sharedUrl = URL(string: sharedPath) else {
                                    return
                                }
     UIApplication.shared.open(sharedUrl)
```