# Open Files app on iPadOS and iOS from my app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipados

On macOS I can do this in order to show a file in Finder:

```
// OPEN THE DIRECTORY IN THE FINDER
NSWorkspace.shared.activateFileViewerSelecting([NSURL].init(arrayLiteral: NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: orthokitPatientsURL.path)) as [URL])
```

How can I do the same on iPadOS/iOS? I have the `path` of the file located in iCloud Drive Documents and I want to show that file location to the user directly in the Files App.

Xcode 12 | iPadOS 14 | Swift 5.4

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61095666/34180660)?

Comment: Solved! I needed to change `file://` with `shared documents://` :)